# Probability of an element in continous sample space

Tags: elementary-probability

Let us consider a continuous sample space $S$ of some random experiment;

Is it true that $p(\{e\}) = 0$ for all $e \in S$ even in the case of non-uniform probability function?

Comment: What is $p(e)$?

Comment: probability of element $e$.

Comment: By definition, a continuous r.v. can not take a sigle value. If $p(e)$ is the density function then it's not always Zero.

Comment: @RobertoCabal "By definition, a continuous r.v. can not take a sigle value." What? You might want to rephrase that because as written, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ZacharySelk You are right, it's poorly written. I mean that the probability of a rv taking a single value (and not laying on a interval) is zero. Is that clear?

Comment: @RobertoCabal That's correct.